# How to save user from non class based view in django?

Tags: django, function, templates, save, django-views

I am trying to create new users to the admin and to the app from **NON Classe Based View** in my django project, I have the model, the view and the template where I am getting the form as it goes in the next code I´m going to show..

**models.py**

```
class Users(models.Model):

# Fields
username = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
password = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True, null=True)
organization_id = models.ForeignKey('ip_cam.Organizations', editable=True, null=True, blank=True)
slug = extension_fields.AutoSlugField(populate_from='created', blank=True)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)

# Relationship Fields
user_id = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)

class Meta:
    ordering = ('-created',)

def __str__(self):
    return u'%s' % self.user_id

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('ip_cam_users_detail', args=(self.slug,))


def get_update_url(self):
    return reverse('ip_cam_users_update', args=(self.slug,))

def __unicode__(self):  # __str__
    self.organization_id=self.request.POST.get('organization_id')
    return unicode(self.user_id, self.organization_id)

# This overrides the standard save method for a user, creating a new user in the admin and getting it to the template at the same time         
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.password = make_password(self.password)
    self.user_id, created = User.objects.get_or_create(username=self.username, password=self.password, is_staff=True)
    self.user_id.groups.add(Group.objects.get(name='admin'))
    self.id = self.user_id.id
    super(Users, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**views.py**

```
def UsersCreate(request):
model = Users

var = {}
var = user_group_validation(request)
userInc = Users.objects.get(id=request.user.id).organization_id.pk
request.session['userInc'] = userInc

if var['group'] == 'superuser':
    object_list = Users.objects.all()
    organization = Organizations.objects.all()
    roles_choice = DefaultLandingPage.objects.all()
if var['group'] == 'admin' or var['group'] == 'user':
    object_list = Users.objects.filter(organization_id=request.session['userInc'])
    organization = Organizations.objects.filter(id=request.session['userInc'])
    roles_choice = DefaultLandingPage.objects.exclude(role=1)
url = request.session['url']
tpl = var['tpl']
role = var['group']
organization_inc = Organizations.objects.filter(id=request.session['userInc'])

template = get_template(app+u'/users_form.html')

return HttpResponse(template.render(locals()))
```

the problem in here is that the save is not working when trying to override it, user is not created at all... can you please help me to see what am I doing wrong this time ? thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you trying to create a User - there's nothing in your view that would create or update a user.

Comment: isn´t the def save() the one to do so ? if not then that should be my mistake... but as you can see I put a def save there in the model Users in the end...

Comment: alright, I see you said in my view, ok I´ll give it a try in there

Comment: If you never call the save method, why would you expect it to do anything? Feel like I'm missing something here...

Comment: ok, let me explain a little bit more, previously I was doing the save process with Class Based Views, then the def save in models worked just fine and created users in the admin User and in my app Users, but there was a filter I had to apply that it seems it would work rendering the form fields from the template directly only, so I changed the UsersCreate View from Class Based to render template with form... is all I did, then def save in models just stopped creating users, now that you are mentioning I have to implement it in my view, I realize that is a good point to hit it... let me try it

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using the generic django class based views, you will have to implement the request's POST and GET functionality yourself. The easiest is to create a form from your user model and handle the request based on whether it's a POST request type or not.

Try this:

forms.py (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/)

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import User

class UserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields = ['username', 'organization_id']
```

views.py

```
from .models import User
from .forms import UserForm

def UsersCreate(request):
    # This function can hadle both the retrieval of the view, as well as the submission of the form on the view.
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()  # This will save the user.
            # Add the user's role in the User Role table below?
        # 
    else:

        # The form should be passed through. This will be processed when the form is submitted on client side via this functions "if request.method == 'POST'" branch.
        form = UserForm()

        var = user_group_validation(request)
        userInc = Users.objects.get(id=request.user.id).organization_id.pk
        request.session['userInc'] = userInc

        if var['group'] == 'superuser':
            object_list = Users.objects.all()
            organization = Organizations.objects.all()
            roles_choice = DefaultLandingPage.objects.all()
        if var['group'] == 'admin' or var['group'] == 'user':
            object_list = Users.objects.filter(organization_id=request.session['userInc'])
            organization = Organizations.objects.filter(id=request.session['userInc'])

            # The line below will ensure that the the dropdown values generated from the template will be filtered by the 'request.session['userInc']'
            form.organisation_id.queryset = organization

            roles_choice = DefaultLandingPage.objects.exclude(role=1)
        url = request.session['url']
        tpl = var['tpl']
        role = var['group']
        organization_inc = Organizations.objects.filter(id=request.session['userInc'])

        template = get_template(app+u'/users_form.html')

    return HttpResponse(template.render(locals()))
```

In your app+u'/users_form.html' file, you can access the UserForm fields as follows:

```
<!-- inside your <form> tag add: -->>
{{ form.username }}
{{ form.organisation_id }}
```

I haven't tested this code but this should get you on the right track.

Comment: ok. thanks a lot for your help, let me hit it and I´ll tell you back

Comment: well, I just tried this implementations and it´s raising an error that sais ... IntegrityError at users/create/ ... NOT NULL constraint failed: users.organization_id_id

Comment: Hi @Prometeo, great, this means that your user is trying to save. This is a step further. I am not sure why the NOT NULL constraint failed for organisation ID as in your User model, you do have "null=True, blank=True" set.
I'd advice to try to get something to work first and debug from there. Remove 'organisation_id' from UserForm's fields and from your template. See if you can save a user then. Put a print statement before the 'if form.is_valid():' line to see if the error occurs before or after form validation. (You could set the organisation id before this line: form.instance.organisation

Comment: yes @user3035260, actually, the user is saved even if throwing this error and by this time I just found the way to have it saving users in my app as well... I resolved that NOT NULL by getting the organization_id from the form and then passing it to my app model in a queryset as the django asked me while debugging... something like this   ... if form.is_valid():    form.organization_id = request.POST.get('organization_id') ... and then ... id=user.id
        Users.objects.create(user_id=User.objects.get(id=id), organization_id=Users.objects.get(organization_id=form.organization_id))